# Illegal character in path at index 4 - Eclipse C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, opengl, error-handling, mingw

I am programming in OpenGL Eclipse using MinGW compiler: -

Everything was working well till now I got this annoying error in my every project.

**Errors occurred during the build**.

**Errors running builder 'CDT Builder' on project 'test 22'.**

**Illegal character in path at index 4: test 22.exe**

IDE:- Eclipse Build: v21.0.0-531062 (actually ADT bundle also installed)
Compiler: - MinGW

I know there are same questions poted already on stackoverflow but their solutions didn't work for me.

How to get rid of this?

Comment: Doesn't like the space between test and 22.exe it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it doesn't allow a space in the project name.